# Geolocation Problems - Absolute Beginners

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm looking through StackOverflow and going through all the web resources but none clarifies for me how to get this done.

I just want to get the latitude number of the user's current position. I want to do that by just firing one method: `getLat()` and that's it.

It won't work. I try return, and it keeps getting undefined. I try changing up variables but that too fails. Forums everywhere say you need to be clever about it because it is 'asynchronous' and the API prevents you from getting getLat() like this, but there should be a way. I don't understand what that particularly means and I would love to get some advice on this.

```
function getLat(){
var lat1;
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
        var coords = position.coords.latitude;
        lat1 = coords; 
    })
}
return lat1;
}

function getLong(){
var lng1;
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
        var coords = position.coords.longitude;
        lat1 = coords; 
    })
}
return lng1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getLocation` functions aren't getting called. And so, the `lat1` and `lng1`, although declared, still have no values hence `undefined`.

Also, the `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. Technically, you don't return the data, you pass it a function, sort of a "todo", when the data is done processing.

Try this instead:

```
//define a function receiving a callback
function getLat(callback){

    //fire the getCurrentposition function
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

        //fire the callback that was passed, 
        //passing to it the latitude
        callback.call(this,position.coords.latitude);
    });
}

//now we use the function
getLat(function(lat){
    //do everything else via the lat variable here!
});

//now do the same for getLng
```